# Find rows in each n hours between date and date + n days

Tags: php, sql, date, logic

I have a table like this

```
start_date          | days | hours
------------------------------------
2014-01-20 01:54:00 | 15   | 7
```

I need to get all rows, eg starting at 20/Jan/2014 and ending at 04/Feb/2014, in a period of 7 hours from `start_date`. If I execute my script each minute, for exemple, I will get the row above when the date and time is `2014-01-20 01:54:00`, `2014-01-20 08:54:00`, and so on.

I already can get all lines from `start_date` and `start_date + days` range'

```
SELECT
    [fields..]
FROM 
    `table`
WHERE
    `start_date` >= NOW() AND
    `start_date` <=  NOW() + INTERVAL `days` DAY
```

Some suggestions of a logic to implement or update my database to solve this?

EDIT:

Addede `PHP` tag , so, any can give-me a idea of how to pass the logic from database to application if it is complex for implement in database the initial idea.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want all the rows in the table which are a multiple of 7 hours after the date.

The idea is to take the difference between the two dates.  Then take the difference in the times and the difference in the dates, convert everything to seconds and do some modular arithmetic.  I think the following does this:

```
select t.*
from table t
where `start_date` >= NOW() AND
      `start_date` <=  NOW() + INTERVAL `days` DAY and
      mod(to_days(subtime(start_date, now())*3600 + timetosec(subtime(start_date, now())), 
          hours * 60 * 60
         ) = 0;
```

Comment: I need to find all rows in n hours (from 1 to 24) basis.